# Complex structure deformations of toric Calabi-Yau 3-folds

Tags: complex-geometry, singularity-theory, deformation-theory

If $X$ is a toric Calabi-Yau 3-fold (so, it is in particular, non-compact), is it necessarily true that $h^{2,1}(X)$ vanishes? (Such a CY 3-fold is termed ``rigid''.)

Comment: What's your definition of a toric Calabi-Yau? The variety $X = \mathbb{A}^3 \setminus 0$ has trivial cotangent bundle and is toric. However, $H^2(X, \Omega^1_X) \simeq H^2(X, \mathcal{O}_X)^{\oplus 3}$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: And if you are interested in deformations, perhaps you want to look at $H^1(X, T_X)$ instead. But then the example $\mathbf{A}^3 \setminus \mathbf{A}^1$ works similarly.

Comment: Perhaps the "right" invariant to look at is $H^2(\overline{X}, \Omega^1_{\overline X}(\log Y)$ where $\overline{X}$ is a smooth compactification of $X$, where the "boundary" $Y=\overline{X} \setminus X$ is a divisor with simple normal crossings, and where $\Omega^1_{\overline{X}}(\log Y)$ denotes differentials with logarithmic poles along $Y$. This group should be independent of the choice of $\overline{X}$ and related to deformations of the pair $(\overline{X}, Y)$. In the toric case (depending on your definition) it should be possible to find $\overline{X}$ toric.